# How to set font for html2pdf in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I need to use a Bengali font while generating my pdf. I have converted the font using fontconverter and it works fine for adding text. I mean the following things are working, i.e., I can see my Bengali Text in the generated pdf -

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFont('SolaimanLipi', 'normal'); 
doc.text("অতীশ", 10, 60);
doc.setFont('SolaimanLipi', 'normal'); // set font
doc.setFontSize(50);
```

However, `doc.setFont('SolaimanLipi', 'normal')` is not working if use `html2pdf`. For instance, following code is not working.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        
pdf.setFont('SolaimanLipi', 'normal');

html2pdf(document.body, pdf, function (canvas) {
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.setAttribute('style', 'position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%; width:500px;font-family:SolaimanLipi;');

            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring');
        }
        );
```

What is the way of setting font for `html2pdf`?

Comment: https://parall.ax/products/jspdf this explains how. For example `doc.setFont('times')`

Comment: it is not working for html2pdf :(

Comment: html2pdf isn't jsPDF which is what you tagged. Consider trying to use `document.body.style`?

Comment: sorry. it is not helping

Comment: https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/doc/font.md